# Changing Colors for Modal Button (Light-Dark)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two modals that each drop down and I want the color to change for the toggle that is activated.

Right now, both toggles appear in white against a colour background. The modal has a white background so I want the toggles to appear in black.

I do not want to use `mix-blend-mode:difference` as it displays text in inverted color against the background and I only want it to appear in white (and then in black after click activation).

```js
// common close button
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  $(`.modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal.modal-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s height 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal.modal-visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal.modal-visible .modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modal-close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.modal-content>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.modal-content>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal.modal-scroll .modal-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal.modal-scroll .modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #CDf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Republique', sans-serif;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.5;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

#righty {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

#lefty {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}

button {
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle" data-modal-id="lefty" id="lefty">LEFT</button>
<button class="toggle" data-modal-id="righty" id="righty">RIGHT</button>

<div class="modal" data-modal-id="lefty">
  <div class="modal-overlay toggle"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="modal-close toggle"></button>
      <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal on the left</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" data-modal-id="righty">
  <div class="modal-overlay toggle"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal on the right</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried various routes in CSS and javascript and struggling to find a simple solution.

Comment: If I understood, you want to set the font-color to black for the inactive modal?

Comment: No the opposite, black for the active modal.

Comment: What I can think of is that you create a boolean called `isActive` that you set to true when the class `modal-active` is toggled. If `isActive == true` then set a `CSS class` to set the font-color to black. Or mayble... Can't you add `color: #000;` to the `moda-visible` class?

Comment: The toggles only activate the modals and are not within them. Color changes to the modal classes adjusts the content but not the buttons... The boolean solution seems complicated for such a simple task but I'll try looking into that.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if it works. And sorry for a too simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [general sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to achieve it :

```css
[data-modal-id="lefty"].modal-visible ~ #lefty, 
[data-modal-id="righty"].modal-visible ~ #righty {
  color: black;
}
```

But you would have to move your buttons after your modals in your HTML :

```js
// common close button
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  $(`.modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal.modal-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s height 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal.modal-visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal.modal-visible .modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modal-close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.modal-content>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.modal-content>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal.modal-scroll .modal-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal.modal-scroll .modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #CDf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Republique', sans-serif;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.5;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

#righty {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

#lefty {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}

button {
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

[data-modal-id="lefty"].modal-visible ~ #lefty, 
[data-modal-id="righty"].modal-visible ~ #righty {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal" data-modal-id="lefty">
  <div class="modal-overlay toggle"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="modal-close toggle"></button>
      <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal on the left</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" data-modal-id="righty">
  <div class="modal-overlay toggle"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal on the right</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="toggle" data-modal-id="lefty" id="lefty">LEFT</button>
<button class="toggle" data-modal-id="righty" id="righty">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: Oh man this is awesome, works incredibly. Thanks so much.